# IIB node exit with no response MYSQL ODBC datasoruce

Tags: unixodbc, ibm-integration-bus

I'm trying to get ODBC working with IIB 10 but my node exit with no response when calling  state.select.
I believe something is wrong with my ODBC setup.
The syslog don't show any error and the debugger crashes on the state.select

This is my code:

```
    try {
     outP = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/tmp/myfile.txt", true)));
outP.println("Start");
        MbSQLStatement state = createSQLStatement( "MYSQL", 
            "SET OutputRoot.XMLNS.integer[] = PASSTHRU('SELECT * FROM " + "test" + "');" );

         state.select( inAssembly, newAssembly );

    } catch (Exception e) {
    outP.println(e);
    outP.flush();
    outP.close();
}
```

Result :
The myfile.txt only contains the text "Start" the catch is never run

My ODBC settings

```
$odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.4

DRIVERS............: /home/ds/iib-10.0.0.13/ie02/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /home/ds/iib-10.0.0.13/ie02/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /home/ds/iib-10.0.0.13/ie02/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/ds/iib-10.0.0.13/server/ODBC/unixodbc/odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

[MySQL]
Description=MySQL driver
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
TraceFile = /tmp/sql.log

[MYSQL]
Description=MYSQL DB
Driver=MySQL
Database=test
Server=127.0.0.1
Port=3306
```

Comment: 1. Can you please show us your implementation after `} catch (Exception e) {`? 2. Did you [configure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/an04230_.htm) the syslog that it shows the IIB log statements?

Comment: I updated the catch but the code crashes so the code is never end up in the catch.  Is there away of configure the syslog in trace mode

Comment: Can you log after `state.select()` the result of `state.getSQLCode();`?

Comment: The code crash after the select() so not possible to call getSQLcode()

Comment: Did you look in `/var/mqsi/common/errors/` or `/var/mqsi/components/<YOUR-BROKER>/stdout` or `/var/mqsi/components/<YOUR-BROKER>/stderr` about some crash information?

Comment: No i don't have a /var/mqsi folder i run the instance locally on Linux are there some log setting i need to turn on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the  attribute `setThrowExceptionOnDatabaseError` to true.

```
state.setThrowExceptionOnDatabaseError(true);
```

> If a database error occurs during the execution of this statement, the behavior is determined by the value of the 'throwExceptionOnDatabaseError' attribute. If set to true (the default value), an exception gets thrown which can be caught if run within a try/catch block

[(source)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKM8N_8.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.plugin.doc/com/ibm/broker/plugin/MbSQLStatement.html#select(com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbMessageAssembly,%20com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbMessageAssembly))